# I want to add a range to the number of choices i have. How do I do that?

Tags: python

```
print("-----ROCK, PAPER, SCISSORS-----")
import random

computer=random.randint(1,5)
user=int(input("Enter Your Choice:\n1=Rock\n2=Paper\n3=Scissors\n4=Lizzard\n5=Spoc\n"))

print("the computer has chosen",computer)

if computer==user:
    print("Tie Game")
elif computer==1 and user==3:
    print("Computer Wins")
elif computer==2 and user==1:
    print("Computer wins")
elif computer==3 and user==2:
    print("Computer wins")
elif computer==4 and user==3:
    print("Computer wins")
elif computer==4 and user==2:
    print("Computer wins")
elif computer==4 and user==1:
    print("Computer wins")
elif computer==5 and user==1:
    print("Computer wins")
elif computer==5 and user==2:
    print("Computer wins")
elif computer==5 and user==3:
    print("Computer wins")
elif computer==5 and user==4:
    print("Computer wins")
else:
    print("You win")
```

Thats my code. I have five possible choices.
However, when i type in the number 10 for my choice, i automaticly get a 'You Win'. How do I add a range so I can only allow five choices.

Comment: have a look on this answer. might help a bit to understand: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/replacements-for-switch-statement-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to check that the user inputs a valid value, if they give you something that is not between 1 and 5, ask them for another number or something like that.  Before you see who won, make sure both are playing the game the right way.

Comment: You already have a lot of if statements looking at the value the user gave you, just add some at the beginning to make sure the user's value is a valid one.

Comment: thxs again Eric ive just made my first major working code with the help of you

Comment: @JackBond Hi, don't forget to mark an answer as accepted if it successfully solved your question. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 1):

```
if user > 5:
    print "please choose again"
else:    
    if computer==user:
        print("Tie Game")
    elif computer==1 and user==3:
        print("Computer Wins")
    elif computer==2 and user==1:
        print("Computer wins")
    elif computer==3 and user==2:
        print("Computer wins")
    elif computer==4 and user==3:
        print("Computer wins")
    elif computer==4 and user==2:
        print("Computer wins")
    elif computer==4 and user==1:
        print("Computer wins")
    elif computer==5 and user==1:
        print("Computer wins")
    elif computer==5 and user==2:
        print("Computer wins")
    elif computer==5 and user==3:
        print("Computer wins")
    elif computer==5 and user==4:
        print("Computer wins")
    else:
        print("You win")
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Even though I used the answer above to help me, I tried your code and it worked the exact same way.